# Juju bootstrap on MaaS

Tags: virtualization, juju, maas, lxd

I have configured all the necessary steps for a MaaS deployement (following the main guide) on my physical machine (8 cores, 32G Mem) with both region and rack controllers on the same machine and configured also the DHCP as shown below.

[image]

I haven't any nodes allocated for now.

I was following the guide for JuJu 2.1 and so I added the maas-cloud and used the same maas-credentials.

However, I'm unable to bootstrap the controller:

> Creating Juju controller "newmaas-controller" on newmaas Looking for
>   packaged Juju agent version 2.1.2 for amd64 Launching controller
>   instance(s) on newmaas... ERROR failed to bootstrap model: cannot
>   start bootstrap instance: cannot run instances: cannot run instance:
>   No available machine matches constraints: mem=3584.0 zone=default

So, to better understand, MaaS and JuJu controllers have to be on separate machines ?

Second, let's suppose that for my Juju-bundle I need both of LXD containers (or KVMs) and physical nodes. Can Juju-controller perform the orchestration without any problems or are we limited on the type of machines ?

Can Juju-controller manage LXD, VMs and Physical machines through MaaS ?

In a particular case, is it possible to perform the charms deployment in the same machine (where maas region/rack controller is installed) ?

Many thanks for suggestions

Comment: Do you have any nodes available that meet the criteria?  It would help to know what nodes you have available

Answer (score 1):

Yes, all on same machine works with LXD. Yes, Landscape with MAAS/JUJU manages everything by my understanding. I too have this issue while trying to bootstrap. It appears that you cannot follow this doc through to completion. 
https://jujucharms.com/docs/stable/getting-started
This is my 3rd attempt on clean builds. I really wish they would fully cook some recipes that simply work and with docs that simply work.